Showing that $\operatorname{Image}(T - 5I) \subset U$
Here is the question I am thinking about:
Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb R$ with basis $(v_1, v_2, v_3).$ Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ be an operator whose matrix with respect to $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ is $$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 4 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 5
\end{pmatrix}$$
Let $p(x) = (x - 3)(x - 4)(x - 5).$ Let $U = \operatorname{span} (v_1, v_2).$
I want to show that $\operatorname{Image}(T - 5I) \subset U$ without using row reduction. Can anyone tell me please how to prove this?

The matrix of $T-5I$ relative to this basis has a third row equal to $0$. P.S., presumably you want to show the image of $T-5I$ is contained in $U$. $T-5I$ is an operator, so it cannot be contained in $U$.

@ArturoMagidin yes you are correct, I mistyped the question.

does having a third row equals zero implies that the image is a subset of U? Why? @ArturoMagidin is that because the $v_i's$ represent the rows of the given matrix?.

It's because what "the matrix of $T$ relative to the basis $v_1,v_2,v_3$} represents/means.

Note that
$$T-5I = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 4 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 5
\end{pmatrix} - 5\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 1 & 2\\
0 & -1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
This means that you can think of $T-5I$ as a linear transformation sending any vector $v=av_1+bv_2+cv_3$ to the vector $(T-5I)v=a\cdot(-2v_1)+b\cdot(v_1-v_2)+c\cdot(2v_1-v_2)$ (the coefficients of the basis vectors are the same as the columns of the matrix). Therefore any $w \in$ Image$(T-5I)$ can be written as a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$, and so must be in $U$

The matrix of the operator $T-5I$ with respect to $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is $$M=\begin{pmatrix}-2&1&2\\0&-1&-1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
In case it is still not obvious, let $v\in V$, and write $v = a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3$ for some $a_1,a_2,a_3\in \mathbb R$. Then the image of $v$ by the operator $T-5I$ can be computed thanks to its matrix representation: $$(T-5I)(v) = \sum_{i=1}^3 \left(\sum_{j=1}^3M_{ij}a_j\right)v_i.$$
However $M_{31} = M_{32} = M_{33} = 0$, thus the coefficient in $v_3$ is $0$, and $(T-5I)(v)\in U$.
Therefore $Im(T-5I)\subseteq U$ by definition of the image of an operator.
